# Html table with double border?

Tags: html, css

How can I create a table with double border: the outer border of 1 px and the inner border of 10px?

This border is only necessary on the table, not between cells.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without adding extra tags that would break your semantics, I would recommend combining `<table>` and `<tbody>` and style them with CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="cow">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cow {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#cow tbody {
    display: block;
    border: 10px solid #ccc;   
}
```

[Working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/bV5Gu/)

An **alternative approach** would be to wrap your table in a containing `<div>` element. You would then apply the 1 pixel border to the `<div>` and the 10 pixel border to the `<table>`. This will definitely work, but will be a less semantic approach. Another downside to this is that the `<div>` width will default to the maximum width available, resulting in a larger 1 pixel border than your actual table width (see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/bV5Gu/1/)).

Answer (score 0):

you can take the table in a **div** tag and then give div tag 1px border and inner table 10 px border.

Answer (score 0):

border-style: double;
border-width: thin;